# Как сгенерировать вложенный массив произвольной длины в groovy на JSON

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

Необходимо сгенерировать JSon на groovy следующего вида

```
    {param1: value1,
    param2: value2,
    someData: [{param3: value3,id: "0"}, {param3: value3,id: "1"}, ..., {param3: value3,id: "n-1"},}
```

Я делаю так

```
    json{
    param1 value1 
    param2 value2
    someData {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            {param3: value3,id: "${i}"}}
    }
```

Но получается что someData просто перезаписывается.

```
    {param1: value1,
    param2: value2,
    someData: [{param3: value3,id: "n-1"}}
```

Как именно дописывать данные в someData?

Так же через someData.add() ничего не добавляется.

```
    {def someData []
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        someData.add({param3: value3,id: "${i}"})
    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такое:

```
def someData = []

1.upto(5, { id ->
    someData.add(['param3': 'value3', 'id': id as String])
})
def payload = ['param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2', 'someData': someData]

log.info(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

Немного полезных ссылок:

- [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)